# Get information from Google Search results using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, search-engine

I am trying to get the information from the below Google search page using Google Apps Script:

[image: Search Image]

Initially, I tried to use `ImportXml` like this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=The%20Bluegrass%20Coffee%20and%20Bourbon%20Lounge","//*[@id='kp-wp-tab-overview']/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[10]/div/div/div/span[2]/span/a/span")
```

However, I got to know that Google no longer allows us to get information from the search results. So I set up a search engine and credentials to get this information. Here is the code snippet:

```
function searchResult() {

  var apiKey = 'your-api-key';
  var cx = 'search-engine-id';
  var query = 'The%20Bluegrass%20Coffee%20and%20Bourbon%20Lounge';

  // Make request to Custom Search API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' + apiKey + '&cx=' + cx + '&q=' + query);
 
  Logger.log(response);
   }
```

However in the `response`, I do not see any information about `Address` or `Phone`. I believe this is due to the fact that I only added the following sites in [Programmable Search Engine](https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/controlpanel/overview), to be searched for the results:

[image: Sites]

Can you please guide me on how to set it up so that it gets information from the entire search page? thank you

Comment: It seems like you should be able to find a better source for this information than scraping a google search result for each business.

Comment: Google provides the facility to use API to get information from search page, so I think we can use that if it is possible.